# Android DrawBitmap in DIP?

Tags: android, pixel

Can I use DrawBitmap with display independant pixels on android?

If not, is there a suitable alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for how to change pixels to dip? then you can use the following code

```
int pixel = 120;
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dip = (int) (pixel* scale + 0.5f);
```

you can use this dip, it will be